# TYPO3 Get started with an ActionController

Tags: typo3, typo3-extensions

I want to achieve something like that:
[image: A diagram where the site communicates via an ActionController, that uses Repo-Pattern to communicate with the database]

But I am struggling with the first milestone already. I want to request the ActionController that should return the status code 200.

That is my code so far:

```
<?php

use Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface;
use T3docs\BlogExample\Domain\Model\Blog;
use T3docs\BlogExample\Exception\NoBlogAdminAccessException;
use TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Annotation\Validate;

class PbiController extends AbstractController
{
    public function GetAction(): ResponseInterface
    {
        return $this->responseFactory
            ->createResponse()
            ->withStatus(200, "ok");
    }
}
```

I started from this: https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/main/en-us/ExtensionArchitecture/Extbase/Reference/Controller/ActionController.html

The first problem is that I have no idea what the URL looks like. And I have no idea if I have to register it myself or if it is done by naming convention.

#### Edit

I forgot to mention I used the sitepackage-builder to have the default template.

Thank you for being so helpful.

Best regards

peni4142

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you must let your controller extend:

```
\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Mvc\Controller\ActionController
```

Seems like you copied the code directly. The blogexample controller extends from an own abstract controller.

So your controller should look like:

```
<?php
namespace MyVendor\MyExt\Controller;

use Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface;
use TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Mvc\Controller\ActionController

class PbiController extends ActionController
{
    public function getAction(): ResponseInterface
    {
        return $this->responseFactory
            ->createResponse()
            ->withStatus(200, "ok");
    }
}
```

Then you need either a plugin or an eid so you can call the action in your controller.
If you register a plugin, then you must add the plugin on a page in your project.
I suggest it would be better to register an eid.
For that implement following in your ext_localconf.php:

```
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['FE']['eID_include']['myCoolPbiEid'] = \MyVendor\MyExt\Controller\PbiController::class . '::getAction';
```

Now you should be able to call your controller with following URL:

```
https://www.domain.tld/index.php?eID=myCoolPbiEid
```

**Edit:**

Be aware of: When implementing the plugin and adressing it via a page, then TYPO3 is rendering the whole page and not only the code of your controller action. So now your action doesn't make really sence any more. If you want your plugin to deliver data, let's say in JSON format i.e., the better way is to use the eID approach.

If you want to add a plugin you can follow the description of the blogexample:

https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/main/en-us/ExtensionArchitecture/Extbase/Reference/FrontendPlugins.html

In your case you must:

1.Configure your plugin in your ext_localconf.php

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

use MyVendor\MyExt\Controller\PbiController
use TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\ExtensionUtility;

defined('TYPO3') or die();

ExtensionUtility::configurePlugin(
    // extension name, matching the PHP namespaces (but without the vendor)
    'MyExt',
    // arbitrary, but unique plugin name (not visible in the backend)
    'PbiPlugin',
    // all actions
    [PbiController::class => 'get'],
    // non-cacheable actions (Only needed if you want uncached output)
    [PbiController::class => 'get']
);
```

2.Register your plugin in /Configuration/TCA/Overrides/tt_content.php

```
<?php

defined('TYPO3') or die();

(static function (): void {
    \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\ExtensionUtility::registerPlugin(
        // extension name, matching the PHP namespaces (but without the vendor)
        'MyExt',
        // arbitrary, but unique plugin name (not visible in the backend)
        'PbiPlugin',
        // plugin title, as visible in the drop-down in the backend, use "LLL:" for localization
        'My cool plugin'
    );
})();
```

After clearing the cache you should now be able to implement the plugin as contentelement on one of your pages. For that add a new contentelement plugins->generalplugin. In the plugin tab of the contentelement you should see your plugin in the dropdown.

To address the plugin in the frontend you can call:

```
https://www.domain.tld/my-page/index.php?tx_myext_pbiplugin[controller]=Pbi&tx_myext_pbiplugin[action]=get
```

**Edit:**

If you use the eID approach the ResponseFactory isn't initialized in the controller. A good way is to return your data in JSON format. You could achive this as follows:

```
<?php
namespace MyVendor\MyExt\Controller;

use Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface;
use TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Mvc\Controller\ActionController
use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Http\JsonResponse;
use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility;

class PbiController extends ActionController
{
    public function getAction(): ResponseInterface
    {
        $data = [
            'MyCoolArrayKey' => 'MyCoolValue'
        ];

        return GeneralUtility::makeInstance(JsonResponse::class, array_values($data));
    }
}
```

Comment: I should go for the plugin, I think. I already have a custom content element that should be included. Also, the controller would not make any sense without the custom content element and will have several actions. Do I have to do some routing for that? Or is the plugin registration already done because I have registered a content element?

Comment: Hi Mogens. Thank you for your time. I was not aware of that! So I go for the eID solution. Maybe you can help me a little more? I updated the post. I have an awkward behavior with the controller(registration, I think). I tried a few things with the namespace, but nothing worked.

Comment: Did you dump the autoloading. I do not use DDEV, but i think you should do "ddev ssh" and then "composer dump".

Comment: BTW: I will reject your edit of my answer, because its not improving the answer or question. The right way would be to add a new question and post the link to the new question here in the comments. Sorry for that.

Comment: Hi Mogens, big thanks to you. The routes seem to be fine, but I get the error:
`Call to a member function createResponse() on null`
The routes seem fine, but the properties of the ActionController appear not to be initialized. Also, when I try to access the view property, I get a null exception.
Thank you for your time again!

Comment: Thats because the ResponseFactory isn't initialized when the action is called via eID.
If you understand german here are some examples on using eID: https://www.typo3lexikon.de/typo3-tutorials/ajax/eid-beispiele.html
If not you could try to translate via google.
Somewhere i also have an example on how to return Data in JSON format. When i find it, i will post it here.

Comment: Added the JSON Example to my answer. Would appriciate if you marked the answer as correct and give m a up. :-)

Comment: Hi, thank you for the time. I usually test the answers before I accept them, but I was swamped. But yeah, it works great. Your answers at all are very great and extensive. I am curious about what is the use case to use the plugin way. Is it about using AJAX?

Comment: No. The eID approach is normally used to answer AJAX requests. Plugins are used to realize custom plugins. In the TYPO3 docs there are good examples to create i.e. Extbase extensions: https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/12.4/en-us/ExtensionArchitecture/Extbase/Examples/Index.html